# Having trouble referring Selenium to a javascript button. [python]

Tags: javascript, python, selenium

Writing a Python script to scrape email addresses from craigslist postings if a reply button exists.  However, I'm having trouble sending a click to the 'reply' javascript button on the craigslist posting page via Selenium.  Here's what I have:

```
def clist():
        i = 'http://sfbay.craigslist.org/eby/ret/5344993908.html'
        driver.get(i)
        reply = driver.find_element_by_class_name("button.reply_button.js-only")
        reply.click()
```

edit: I've also tried `driver.find_element_by_css_selector` with the same selector, and `driver.find_element_by_xpath` with xpath being `\\button`.  All throw similar errors.

**Actual Output:**

```
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"button.reply_button.js-only"}
```

**What I expect:** for the script to actually click the reply button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is only one button with class `reply_button`, so you can simplify the class selector.

```
from selenium import webdriver
browser = webdriver.Firefox()


def clist():
    url = 'http://sfbay.craigslist.org/eby/ret/5344993908.html'
    browser.get(url)
    reply = browser.find_element_by_class_name('reply_button')
    reply.click()

clist()
```